# Check data is coming from external source is positive or negative & fetch it's value

Tags: java, android

I have 3 byte data, that is coming from external source. i used long to store that data, now i need to check coming data is negative or positive. for that i used the code :

```
long min = Long.MIN_VALUE;
     long i = ((longData+ min) & 0xFF) - min;

     if(i <0)
     {
         System.out.print(i+"negative");
     }
     else
         System.out.print(i+"positive");
```

but that is not working, Could you please guide me.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would depend on what you mean by "negative" and how you convert your 3 bytes to a `long` value. If you store the three bytes in the three least significant bytes of the long and if "negative" means that the highest bit is set, then you should be able to use:

```
if ((longData & (1L<<23)) != 0) {
    System.out.print(i+"negative");
}
else {
    System.out.print(i+"positive");
}
```

Comment: thanks Klas, yes i am doing this in same way... but ....if (longData & (1L<<23)) condition is not possible in java code.

Comment: @Andy: Corrected my answer.

Comment: @Andy @KlasLindbäck: Watch your operator precedence. [**`!=` has higher precedence than `&`.**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: @michael Thanks for pointing that out. Added an extra set of parenthesis.